# Iris Mechanism Blades for 3d Printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I am interested in 3D Printing an iris mechanism but tinkercad doesn't give me the versatility I need, so I am using blender but I am trying to figure out how to split a circle into the iris blades so they're all even. I have split my octogon into triangle divisions, but I'm having a hard time trying to separate the triangles to mimic the shapes in the similar to the blades in the image below:
(I apologize in advance for any improper verbiage, but I am still new to blender.)

[image]

Does anyone know if there is a modifier or a tool to separate my shapes below?
[image]

Comment: you can select faces and press p to separate faces into new mesh,or also  you can select connecting edge and pres v to rip edge and repeat other edges to split in same mesh. But how are you going to obtain 5 blades with that octagon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. Actually, to model this blade, you have first to understand the underlying geometry. Its the intersection of 3 circles that make up that shape. In the following I will show you how to make that shape (with the hole) step by step.

**EDIT:**
**0. go into Top Ortho by pressing <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>**

1. Create a circle with 30 vertices
   [image]
2. Go into Edit Mode (press <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and make sure the circle is selected (if not press <kbd>A</kbd> until it is). Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the circle. Before confirming the action press <kbd>Y</kbd> and type in 1 to move the circle by one up.
   [image]
3. Press <kbd>.</kbd> (not on your Numpad) to select Cursor Pivotcenter. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> again and this time press <kbd>R</kbd> and type in -72 to rotate your Circle correctly.
   [image]
4. Next select the vertex at [0, 1, 0] (where the 3D Cursor is in the next image) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Select Cursor to Selected in the popup menu. Your Cursor should now be where it is in the image. Then create a Circle by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and make sure it has 6 vertices.
   [image]
5. Activate the little magnet in the bar at the bottom of the 3D Viewport. Select Vertex in the combobox right next to it. Now press <kbd>R</kbd> and let the rotation snap in place exactly as shown in the image below. Then Confirm by <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   [image]
6. Now Scale with <kbd>S</kbd> and let it snap to the same vertex. Again shown below.
   [image]
7. Reset your Cursor to the Center py pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and selecting Cursor to Center. Make sure the setting with the magnet stayed the same and press <kbd>R</kbd>. Let the rotation snap in place like shown below and confirm.
   [image]
8. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and let it snap like shown below before confirming.
   [image]
9. Select the vertices as shown in the image below and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. Select At Center in the popup menu.
   [image]
10. Next up you have to remove all temporary vertices. Make sure you are in Wireframe Mode (to the right of the Edit Mode combobox). If you are not in Wireframe Mode press <kbd>Z</kbd> to enter it. Press <kbd>C</kbd> to use the circle selection tool and select the vertices shown below. When finished press <kbd>X</kbd> and select Vertices to delete them.
    [image]
11. Select everything whats left (press <kbd>A</kbd> until that is the case). Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select Remove Doubles. (In 2.8 press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select By Distance)
12. Select the two vertices like shown below and press <kbd>X</kbd> and select Edges.
    [image]
13. Select every vertex around the big face (every vertex except two which are part of the hexagon) and press <kbd>F</kbd> to make a Face. Select (only) the 6 vertices of the hexagon and press <kbd>F</kbd>. Then press <kbd>I</kbd> and adjust the size of the hole that you what to be in there. Then after you confirmed press <kbd>X</kbd> and Faces to make the hole.
    [image]
14. The following part is completly optional and because you are a beginner it may be hard to do for you. In the picture below I made a beautiful topology to be used with the Subsurf Modifier. I made that mostly by using the Knife Tool (<kbd>K</kbd>). If you want you can copy my topology with that tool. The most important step here is to add the Edge Creases at the inner tip. Select the 3 vertices that are the closest to the 3D Cursor in the image and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Move your mouse until a Crease +1.000 appears in the bottom left corner of the 3D Viewport and confirm with <kbd>LMB</kbd>.
    [image]
15. Press <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to add a Subsurf Modifier and exit the Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
    [image]
16. Add a Solidify Modifier in the Modifier Tab (shown in the image above) by clicking on Add Modifier and select it there. You can then Adjust the Thickness of the blade and Apply that modifier.
17. Enjoy tinkering

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This was a perfected illustrated example. Another thanks for the cut tool suggestion, after I looked it up it really helped!